# How to update and submit a reactive form using the same submit button in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a view component like this. The edit button routes me to the register component where I'm updating the form using patchvalue.

[image]

The problem is: I am updating and registering the form using the same button, so the values are populated during editing, but another instance of the same bookingId is also created. I just want to edit the form without creating any additional duplicate id

**registration-form.component.ts**

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn,AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {RegisterService} from './register.service';
import {ViewService} from '../view-component/view.service';
import {Booking} from '../booking.model';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-form',
  templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent implements OnInit {

  category:any=[
    {id:1, dining:'Fine Dining'},
    {id:2, dining:'Buffet'},
    {id:3, dining:'Outdoor'}
  ];


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private register:RegisterService,
    private route:ActivatedRoute, private view:ViewService) { }
  
  isAddMode:boolean;
  bookingForm:FormGroup;
  unamePattern =/^[ A-Za-z_@.$/#&+-]*$/;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookingForm=this.fb.group({
      bookingId:['', [Validators.required, validateId]],
      guestName:['', Validators.required],
      guestId:['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.unamePattern)]],
      gender:['', Validators.required],
      categoryName:['', Validators.required],
      bookingDate:['', Validators.required]
    })

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      params=>{
        const bookingId=params.get('id');
        if(bookingId){
          this.getBooking(bookingId)
        }
      }
    )
  }

  getBooking(id){
    this.view.getBooking(id).subscribe(
      (user)=>this.editBooking(user),
      (err:any)=>console.log(err)
    )
  }

  editBooking(user:Booking){
      this.bookingForm.patchValue({
        bookingId:user.bookingId,
        guestName:user.guestName,
        guestId:user.guestId,
        gender:user.gender,
        categoryName: user.categoryName,
        bookingDate: user.bookingDate
      })
  }


  book(data:Booking){
this.register.registerBooking(data)
.subscribe    
    (
      (res)=>{
      console.log("Data returned is" , res);
      })
  }


}
```

**registration.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title">
            <h3>Book a Buffet</h3></div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="bookingForm" (ngSubmit)="book(bookingForm.value)">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bookingId" class="control-label">
                Booking Id:
            </label>
            <input name="bookingId" type="text" formControlName="bookingId" class="form-control">
            <div id="bookingIdErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.bookingId.invalid">
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.bookingId.errors?.required &&
                bookingForm.controls.bookingId.touched">
                Enter an ID
              </span>
              <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.bookingId.errors.IdError &&
              bookingForm.controls.bookingId.touched && bookingForm.controls.bookingId.value!==' ' ">
                {{bookingForm.controls.bookingId.errors.IdError.message}}
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="guestName" class="control-label">
            Guest Name:
        </label>
        <input name="guestName" type="text" formControlName="guestName" class="form-control">
        <div id="guestNameErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.guestName.invalid">
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.guestName.errors?.required &&
            bookingForm.controls.guestName.touched">
            Enter a Name
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="guestId" class="control-label">
            Guest Id:
        </label>
        <input name="guestId" type="text" formControlName="guestId" class="form-control">
        <div id="guestIdErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.guestId.invalid">
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.guestId.errors?.required &&
            bookingForm.controls.guestId.touched">
            Enter an Id
          </span>
          <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.guestId.errors?.pattern &&
          bookingForm.controls.guestId.touched">
          Enter valid Id
        </span> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender" class="control-label">Gender : </label>
        <input id="male" type="radio" value="male" name="gender" formControlName="gender" >
        <label for="male"> Male</label>
        <input id="female" type="radio" value="female" name="gender" formControlName="gender" >
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <div id="genderErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.gender.invalid">
            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.gender.errors?.required &&
            bookingForm.controls.gender.touched">
            Enter a gender
          </span>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoryName">Category: </label>
    <select formControlName="categoryName" class="form-control" class="control-label">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option *ngFor="let cat of category" [value]="cat.dining">{{cat.dining}}</option>
    </select>
    <div id="categoryErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.categoryName.invalid">
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.categoryName.errors?.required &&
        bookingForm.controls.categoryName.touched">
        Enter a category
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="bookingDate">Date of booking</label>
    <input type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control" formControlName="bookingDate"> 
    <div id="bookingDateErr" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.bookingDate.invalid">
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="bookingForm.controls.bookingDate.errors?.required &&
        bookingForm.controls.bookingDate.touched">
        Enter a date
      </span>
      
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
         [disabled]="!bookingForm.valid">Book</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Should I create a new Update button here or is it possible to update and post using the same button- Book?
Please help

Comment: When you say this "so the values are populated during editing, but another instance of the same bookingId is also created" , you mean another instance is created in database, right?

Comment: Naveen Chahar- Yes

Comment: You can check out the approach provided in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to modify your query in backend. Instead of simply saving the data in the database, first do a search query using the 'bookingId' field on your collection. If you find any data for that particular bookingId, it means that you need to edit/update the data and not register it. If you do not find any data with the same bookingId in your collection that means you need to register this data in your collection.

For example, right now your code looks something like this is inside the register api on the backend -

```
    booking.save(data)   //save the incoming data in collection
```

Change your code to something like this:

```
    booking.find({bookingId: data.bookingId},(err,record)=>{      //find record for given bookingId
        if(record){
           booking.findAndUpdate(data);   //if record already exist then update it
        }
         else{
           booking.save(data)       //if record doesnt exist then create it
         }
     }
    )
```